# kubernetes: validating a yaml file against a custom resource

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-apiserver, kubernetes-custom-resources

Assuming I have a custom resource on my `k8s` cluster exposed on a proprietary api endpoint, e.g. `somecompany/v1`

Is there a way to validate a `.yaml` manifest describing this resource?

It his a functionality the custom resource provider should expose or it is natively supported by `k8s` for CRDs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a look on a simple example:

```
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: myresources.stable.example.com
spec:
  group: stable.example.com
  versions:
    - name: v1
      served: true
      storage: true
  scope: Namespaced
  names:
    plural: myresources
    singular: myresource
    kind: MyResource
    shortNames:
    - mr
  validation:
    openAPIV3Schema:
      required: ["spec"]
      properties:
        spec:
          required: ["cert","key","domain"]
          properties:
            cert:
              type: "string"
              minimum: 1
            key:
              type: "string"
              minimum: 1
            domain:
              type: "string"
              minimum: 1
```

`spec.validation` field describes custom validation methods for your custom resource. You can block the creation of resources using validation if certain fields are left empty. In this example, `OpenAPIV3Schema` validation conventions is used to check the type of some fields in our custom resource. We ensure that `spec` , `spec.cert` , `spec.key` , and `spec.domain`  fields of the custom resource do exist and that they are of a String type. Users can also use [validatingadmissionwebhook](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/admission-controllers/) as a validation schema. You can find more about restrictions for using this field in the [official documentation](https://v1-12.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-kubernetes-api/custom-resources/custom-resource-definitions/#validation).